# Why do the gauge bosons fix the couplings of the SM?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

In chapter [Chapter 16: Grand Unified Theories](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-guts.pdf) in the very first paragraph, the author states

> Note the SM gauge interactions of quarks and leptons are
> completely fixed by their gauge charges.

Why is that ?

Comment: The quote you give suggests that the gauge charges uniquely fix all the interactions between quarks, leptons and bosons. It is a consequence of all particles lying in some representations of gauge groups. The representation is encoded with the value of the charge, all the interactions are determined by representations. I can't see anything about "gauge bosons fixing the couplings"...